# file processing (for file with more than one fields) and problems associated with it

Tags: c++, file-io, file-processing

here is a code i wrote to create the symtab of a sic/xe .asm file....

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<fstream>
 #include<iomanip>
 #include"aviasm.h"
 using namespace std;

 void aviasm::crsymtab()
{

ofstream outs("symtab.txt",ios::out);//creating the symtab
ofstream outi("intermfile.txt",ios::out);//creating the intermediate file
ifstream in("asmfile.txt",ios::in);//opening the asmfile which i have already written
in.seekg(0,ios::beg);


char c;
string str[3];
string subset;
long locctr=0;
int i=0;


while((c=in.get())!=EOF)
{
    in.putback(c);
    while((c=in.get())!='\n')
    {
        in.putback(c); //putting back the first encountered letter
        in>>str[i++];  //the asm file has three or less fields in every row
    }

    if(str[0].size()!=0 && str[1].size()!=0 && str[2].size()!=0)//if all 3 are there
    {

        if(str[1]=="start")
        {
            outi<<hex<<locctr;
            outs<<str[1]<<" "<<locctr<<"\n";
            outs<<resetiosflags(ios::hex);
            outi<<" "<<str[0]<<" "<<str[1]<<" "<<str[2]<<"\n";
            locctr=stol(str[2],0,16);
        }//str[1]=start
     }//end of all the three fields
}
in.close();
outi.close();
outs.close();
}//end of crsymtab
```

.....here is a sample [sic/xe .asm file](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=8rh8W).....note that in the above code i have not included the entire coded because the problem occurs even if i comment out the entire portion of the code except the above...the problem that occurs is whenever i run the code:

1. A message box with: `'Unhandled exception at 0x00ba7046 in aviasm.exe: 0xC0000005:
     Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc.'` appears and my program enters
    debugging   mode...also a file named `iosfwd(std::char_traits<char>)` appears with an
    arrow at the line 
    `_Left=_Right;` of the following function:

   `static void __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL assign(_Elem& _Left, const _Elem& _Right)
       {   // assign an element
       _Left = _Right;
       }`
2. Also, I output a few words to the console at the start and end of the block
   `str[1]="start"` to check whether this function was working...although both lines were
   working and I am also sure that input is being successfully taken by the program from 
   the asm file(I have checked this),no lines are being output to intermfile and symtab...plz help??

Comment: "the problem that occurs is whenever i run the code:" and "exception being thrown at time of compiling" do not seem to fit well together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your program inside a debugger. If you are using Windows, then MSVC provides a debug environment. If you are using Linux, compile your program with `-g`, and run the gdb debugger: `gdb ./myprog`. You would immediately discover that on this line:

```
in>>str[i++];  //the asm file has three or less fields in every row
```

`i` has a value of 4, which exceeds the size of the `str` array.

Comment: @rob...i has the maximum value of 3(not 4)...but i solved the problem by writing if(i<=1) i++;....but still exception is thrown when i run the code

Comment: @rob...also why the code is not being input to the intermfile and symtab if it is being successfully taken out from the asmfile

Comment: The data is *not* being successfully input from the asmfile. Your program crashes while extracting data from the asmfile. Therefore, you never reach the lines which output to the other files.

Comment: @rob...sorry i misunderstood your solution....u were correct...i have identified the problem...1 upvote from me

Comment: @rob....but this is still not a solution for why the content of str are not being input into symtab and intermfile....because i did cout<<str[0]<<str[1]<<str[2] and it printed the first line after which the str index went out of hand...but at least the first line could have printed in the symtab and intermfile....even if i do outi<<"hey"; hey is not being printed in intermfile

Comment: @avinash -- Writes to disk files are buffered, which means that the actual writing is deferred until some time *after* the call to `ostream::operator<<`. If your program crashes after the `<<`, but before the system decides to write, you'll never see the data.  If this is the case, change your `<<"\n"` to `<<std::flush<<"\n"` (or, equivalently, `<<std::endl`).