# taking input from a file

Tags: c++, file, file-io, file-processing

i have the following file named asmfile.txt

```
copy start 1000
read  ldx zero
      rd indev
rloop tix k100
```

in order to take linewise input from this file i wrote the following code....

```
void aviasm::crsymtab()
{


ifstream in(asmfile,ios::in);//opening the asmfile
in.seekg(0,ios::beg);


char c;
string str[3];
string subset;
long locctr=0;
int i=0;


while((c=in.get())!=EOF)
{
    in.putback(c);
    str[0]="";
    str[1]="";
    str[2]="";

    while((c=in.get())!='\n')
    {

        in.putback(c);
        in>>str[i];
        i==2?i=0:i++;  //limiting i to 2....

    }

    cout<<str[0]<<" "<<str[1]<<" "<<str[2]<<endl;
}

in.close();
}
```

//now the problem is that the first three lines are being successfully input into str...but the last line is not being input to str....i know this because when running the program on console i see...

```
copy start 1000
read  ldx zero
rd indev
```

'rd indev' indentation changes because str[0]="rd" and str[1]="indev".....plz tell me why the fourth line is not being input into str....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to why your code fails: `while((c=in.get())!='\n')` enters infinite loop when there's no new-line character in the last line of asmfile.

Change `i==2?i=0:i++;` to i++ and move `int i=0;` in while loop, edit asmfile so it'll have a new-line character behind last line and your code will work.

That said, you really SHOULD be doing it like Rene suggested. Code like this is messy and error prone.

Comment: @jrok....i dnt think so because before every line is input the the code checks if it is a EOF so at the end of last line it will get an EOF and the outer while loop will be ended...but even if i agree to u and change the inner loop too to while((c=in.get)!='\n' && c!=EOF)...this doesnt explain why the last line doesnt input to str because the infinite loop should start once last line has been entered

Comment: well, because your program never gets out of the loop and can't reach the cout expression. See edited answer.

Comment: @jrok...yeah u were right....it gets caught bcoz there is an eof and not a '\n' at the end of file right?

Comment: @jrok...ur answer fixed the code though i still have one doubt...i changed the inner while loop to while((c=in.get())!='\n' && c=EOF) and ran the code...though the infinite recursion ended but the output to console was tix k100 rloop instead of rloop tix k100...but ur method i.e. changing the i==2?i=0:i++ to i++ and i=0 in outer loop output rloop tix k100...why did my method fail

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what's the aim of reading the file character by character and putting them back into the stream. The line

```
string str[3];
```

defines strings `str[0]` to `str[2]`. Writing to non-existing `str[3]`is undefined behaviour. A cleaner approach would be

```
std::ifstream in(asmfile);
std::vector<std::string> lines;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(in, line))
{
  lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Afterwards `lines.size()` gives the numbers of lines read successfully.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
{
  std::cout << i << " :  " << lines[i] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @Rene....i intend to read the line from the asm file and then output it to another file after some modifications...but i saw that only the first three lines were being output to the another file...so i decided to check whether the fourth line is being read at all...so when i output all the lines as encountered to the console only the first three lines were output....and can u plz point where am i writing to str[3] in the code....also i would rather appreciate if u point out the mistake in my code rather than writing a code of ur own....plz...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble debugging your code, because I don't understand your intent -- what is the deal with the `get()` and `pushback()` calls?. So, instead of answering your immediate question, let me rewrite your code:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

const char * asmfile("/tmp/asm.txt");
void crsymtab()
{
  std::ifstream in(asmfile); // opening the asmfile

  std::string line;
  while(std::getline(in, line)) {
    std::istringstream sline(line);
    std::string str[3];
    if(sline.peek() == ' ')
      sline >> str[1] >> str[2];
    else
      sline >> str[0] >> str[1] >> str[2];
    std::cout << str[0] << " " << str[1] << " " << str[2] << "\n";
  }
}

int main() { crsymtab(); }
```

Comment: @Rob....the intent is the same as that of the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516868/file-processing-for-file-with-more-than-one-fields-and-problems-associated-with) i asked u about yesterday....a new problem has cropped up though i can read the first three lines and output them to the symtab and intermfile but the third line was not being output to the files so i decided to check whether it is being read at all...so when i output all the lines encountered to the console only the first three lines were output...